# Django url is not picking the updated django view

Tags: python, django

Use Case :
When ever i am tryng to access my url e.g.http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/

it always picks the old code from dashbaord/views.py

**Old view :**

```
def dashboard(request):
    context = {'data':[29,25,25]}
    template='dashboard.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
```

**Updated view**

```
def dashboard(request):
    abc='pankaj'
    context = {'data':[15,20,10]}
    template='dashboard.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
```

When i am loading this page, it gives some error and shows the old view code not the latest one.

What i have done.

1. I am running server locally by command

> python manage.py runserver

2. deleted all previous .pyc files

But, the problem still remains the same .

Any input in this direction would be a great help!!

Comment: Did you make sure to save the file, or restarting your computer? Cache can be very tricky.

Comment: Have you stopped and started the local server?!

Comment: Clear the cache. If you still get the error, show us the error.

Comment: make sure that your local server restarted and try hard reload. What is the error shown?

Comment: @hybrid Thanks , restarting the machine has done the trick for me!!

Comment: What is important as Higor Rossato has pointed out: it does not help you to just start the server anew. You need to make sure to have stopped it first.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with

1. Restarting the server
2. Clear cache from browser and hard reload
3. Save the file and delete old Pyc

However , what worked for me is, **restarting** my machine.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Django you should always migrate the changes before running the server.

python manage.py migrate

python manage.py runserver